# DATOS JSON A HTML UBICACION EN EL MAPA

Tags: html, json, estructuras-de-datos, google-api

hola tengo que realizar la siguiente practica, listar el domicilio de los cajeros automáticos los cuales se encuentran contenidos en objeto ATM y consta de 5 elementos cada elemento de este objeto contiene la propiedad AddressLine la cual corresponde a la dirección del cajero la cual se tendrá que listar dinámicamente en el frontend agregando una función a cada elemento que permita visualizar la ubicación en un mapa de google maps, obteniendo la latitud y la longitud del objeto JSON devuelto por  app.php donde contendrá otro objeto llamado GeoLocation donde se encontraran estos datos.

el json que regresa es el siguiente pero no se como convertir ese arreglo a texto de HTML, y no se como se usa la GeoLotacion para mostrar los datos en google maps, estoy empezando en la programación, eh visto videos pero no le eh entendido muy bien  y no se si tengan un código que realice algo similar a lo que necesito o si me pudieran ayudar con la estructura.

```
      [{"direccion":"REVOLUCION 203, CENTRO, SALITRE, DURANGO, 
   CP98500","altitud":20.456040607375712,"longitud":-100.61895204554868}, 
    {"direccion":"CONSTITUYENTES 550, CENTRO, SALITRE, DURANGO, 
   CP98500","altitud":20.545323040035257,"longitud":20.545323040035257},
   {"direccion":"BENITO JUAREZ 108, CENTRO, MATAMOROS, MICHOACAN, 
    CP38160","altitud":20.545323040035257,"longitud":20.545323040035257},
   {"direccion":"MIGUEL HIDALGO 106, CENTRO, DOLORES, HIDALGO. 
   CP38160","altitud":20.545323040035257,"longitud":20.545323040035257}]
```

gracias.,

Comment: Saludos y bienvenido, por curiosidad, ¿has intentado algo? Por otro lado, aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 aumentarán la chance de obtener una buena respuesta :D